# How to retrieve data from related Models?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am new to Django and I am trying to create a site to manage class information for example students and their statistics. When I click a class I can see the details of the class and which students are in this class. However, I want to have also an average score of every student but I don't know how to retrieve the data from my Statistics Model. I tried select_related but didn't work. Thank you in advance.

I want to do this in django:

```
SELECT class.id, class.name, class.day_and_time, student.name, average(statistics.dictation_score), average(statistics.grammar_score)
FROM classes
INNER JOIN students on student_class = class.id
INNER JOIN statistics on student = student.id
WHERE class.id =(some number)
```

My models .py file:

```
class Classes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    day_and_time= models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("classesapp:class_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})


class Students(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    student_class =  models.ForeignKey(
        Classes, related_name = 'students', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("classesapp:student_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

class Statistics(models.Model):
    student= models.ForeignKey(
        Students, related_name='statistics', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True
    )
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    dictation_score = models.FloatField()
    writing_score = models.FloatField()
    test_score = models.FloatField()
    grammar_score = models.FloatField()
    in_class_performance = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-date"]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("classesapp:classes_list")
```

My views .py file:

```
class ClassesDetailView(DetailView):
    stats  = models.Students.objects.select_related('statistics')
    context_object_name = "class_detail"
    model = models.Classes
    template_name = "classesapp/class_detail.html"
```

What I want to do:
[Image from the site what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLPzK.png)

Comment: Have a look at how Django [aggregations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/) work and in particular the section on [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset). In your `DetailView` you should override `get_queryset()` or just the class attribute `queryset` to add the average score as annotation for each student.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer. I looked at the documentation but still couldn't find a solution for my problem. However, found a solution to another problem I had. Thank you again. I am trying this but still doesn't work queryset = models.Classes.objects.select_related('students','statistics').annotate(av_dictation=Avg('statistics__dictation_score'))